# Installing local module + submodules using cpanp

Tags: perl, cpan

I have the following project structure:

```
A/
|- B.pm
|- B/
 |- one.pm
 |- two.pm
 |- three.pm
```

in `B.pm` I have:

```
package A::B;

use A::B::one;
use A::B::two;
use A::B::three;
```

Now, I'm trying to install this module locally using `cpanp`. When in the `A` directory I simply run:

```
cpanp i .
```

It says *Module 'A' installed successfully*, however, when I list the content of my `$PERL5LIB` directory, all I can see is `B.pm` instead of `A/`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You need to create a distribution out of your modules such that `cpanp` knows what to include when installing

Comment: See [module-starter](https://metacpan.org/pod/module-starter) for an easy way to do it

Comment: @HåkonHægland Thanks for the info. Are there benefits using this approach locally too?   (That is if I don't want to distribute my module.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is probably not the recommended way to do it but for those looking for a quick-and-dirty solution, just move everything to a `lib` directory.

For me it looks like:

```
A-B
└── lib
    └── A
        ├── B
        │   ├── one.pm
        │   ├── three.pm
        │   └── two.pm
        └── B.pm
```

When in the `A-B` directory, I simply run:

```
cpan .
```

As I just want to install my module locally this approach worked for me but let me know if you think there are good reasons to use tools like [module-starter](https://metacpan.org/pod/module-starter) (as suggested by @HåkonHægland) or at least write my own Makefile.PL (which is actually the approach I ended up with as I wanted to list dependencies).